# How to programmatically clear a brush selection in echarts

Tags: javascript, brush, echarts

I'm using [echarts library](https://ecomfe.github.io/echarts-doc/public/en/).
I'm creating histograms with bar charts, and using brush selection to highlight bars.
Also I want to programmatically select / unselect bars.
Following echarts documentation and examples, I understand that this kind of actions are done by using `chart.dispatchAction` but no brush action is documented or showed.
The only related things documented is an option (`brush.removeOnClick`) which, only if `brush.brushMode === 'single'` allows to clear the brush selection on click.
How is it possible to programmatically create / clear brush selections?
thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an undocumented `brush` action;

Usage example:

Clear brush with the command `clear`:

```
chart.dispatchAction({
  type: 'brush',
  command: 'clear',
  areas: [],
});
```

Create a brush selection (at least in a bar chart with `axisType === 'category'`) with:

```
chart.dispatchAction({
  type: 'brush',
  areas: [
    {
      brushType: 'lineX',
      xAxisIndex: 0,
      coordRange: [from, to],
    },
  ],
});
```

Where `coordRange` is an array of 2 axis ticks indexes.

There are a lot of undocumented things in echarts.